# Does nesting if statements improve performance or have other advantages over flat if statements?

Tags: java, c#, if-statement, optimization, compilation

I have a slightly clumsy series of if statements that by habit I nest like this:

```
// Cannot collide with right
    if(direction.x < 0)
    {
        // Cannot collide with top
        if(direction.y < 0)
        {
            // Check left and bottom
        }
        // Cannot collide with bottom
        else if (direction.y > 0)
        {
            // Check left and top
        }
        // Cannot collide with top or bottom
        else
        {
            // Check left only

        }
    }
    // Cannot collide with left
    else if (direction.x > 0)
    {
        // Cannot collide with top
        if(direction.y < 0)
        {
            // Check right and bottom
        }
        // Cannot collide with bottom
        else if (direction.y > 0)
        {
            // Check right and top
        }
        // Cannot collide with top or bottom
        else
        {
            // Check right only

        }
    }
```

However I find it a little hard to read and thought it might be easier to follow as a flat set of if statements, somewhat like a switch:

```
// Cannot collide with right or top
    if(direction.x < 0 && direction.y < 0)
    {
        // Check left and bottom
    }
    // Cannot collide with right or bottom
    else if(direction.x < 0 && direction.y > 0)
    {
        // Check left and top
    }
    // Cannot collide with right, top or bottom
    else if(direction.x < 0)
    {
        // Check left only
    }
    // Cannot collide with left or top
    else if (direction.x > 0 && direction.y < 0)
    {
        // Check right and bottom
    }
    // Cannot collide with left or bottom
    else if (direction.x > 0 && direction.y > 0)
    {
        // Check right and top
    }
    // Cannot collide with left, top or bottom
    else
    {
        // Check right only
    }
```

The obvious drawback to this is that I'm re-checking a condition multiple times. In this case it's so small I can't imagine it makes any difference, but my questions are:

1. Can/do modern compilers for C#, Java etc optimize the second example to remove the repeated checks?
   This would be fine in this example but might cause problems if the condition checking also had side effects.
2. Also in general, which approach would be favoured?

Comment: Your second example is not in any way flattened, every else if adds a new layer of nesting as it is equivalent to `else { if(predicate) { ...`, you just don't need the `{`.

Comment: I think reading your code comments alone shows which way should be preferred

Comment: Its better to avoid nested if statements wherever possible. Code becomes complex to read when we have deep nested if statements. This is not advisable with PMD tool.

Answer (score 0):

The AND statements will be shortcut by the compiler in C#, so if direction.x <= 0, the second clause in your else if statements will not be evaluated, so there is no need to nest on the basis of "direction > 0".

Comment: Except if `direction.x` is declared `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

I would favor the first approach because it reduces code duplicates (beyond that it might be slightly faster - in case of `volatile` attributes the variables have to be re-read).

What happens if you need to change the `direction.x < 0` condition to `direction.x > 1` (might not be the best example here but you get the idea...)? You only have to change it in **one** place.

Also I think the first approach is easier to understand: when you follow the code, you know that if you're in the first branch of the `if` statement, it "Cannot collide with right" while with the 2nd approach you always have to think through the whole condition, and **also** all the conditions of previous `if` statements to know if you even get there.

### Improvement

Your code can be improved by separating the conditions with the actual code you want to make, by really turning it into a `switch`.

For this we'll use these constants:

```
static final int LEFT   = 0x01;
static final int RIGHT  = 0x02;
static final int TOP    = 0x10;
static final int BOTTOM = 0x20;
```

And the code:

```
final int dir = (d.x < 0 ? LEFT : d.x > 0 ? RIGHT  : 0)
              + (d.y < 0 ? TOP  : d.y > 0 ? BOTTOM : 0);

switch (dir) {
case LEFT:           // Check left only
    break;
case RIGHT:          // Check right only
    break;
case LEFT + TOP:     // Check left and top
    break;
case LEFT + BOTTOM:  // Check left and bottom
    break;
case RIGHT + TOP:    // Check right and top
    break;
case RIGHT + BOTTOM: // Check right and bottom
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Premature optimization is evil.

Readability-wise I'd do something like

```
[Flags]
enum Direction
{
    None = 0,
    Top = 1 << 0,
    Bottom = 1 << 1,
    Left = 1 << 2,
    Right = 1 << 3,
}
```

And then

```
var d = (x > 0 ? Direction.Right : (x < 0 ? Direction.Left : Direction.None)) |
    (y > 0 ? Direction.Top : (y < 0 ? Direction.Bottom : Direction.None));
switch(d)
{
    case Direction.Left:
        ...
        break;
    case Direction.Right | Direction.Bottom:
        ...
        break;
    ...
}
```